# Facebook SDK 3.20.0 - only admin can share but other user can not share

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to share image and text on Facebook wall using android facebook sdk from my application. User can successfully login using facebook account but when try to share on his wall he got the access denied for publish. When i login using admin account i can successfully login and share on facebook.

Here is my code for share on facebook

```
public class FacebookShareActivity extends Activity {

private static final String PERMISSION = "publish_actions";

private Bundle mExtras;
private String mPostText;
public ImageView mImageView;
public TextView mPostTextView;
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private Boolean mPendingAction;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook_share);

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPendingAction = false;

    // Used to print the hash key
    getHashKey();

    // Get the intent that started this activity
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mExtras = intent.getExtras();
    if ((mExtras == null) || mExtras.size() < 1)
    {
        // Nae extras!!! nothing to share, git tae!
        finish();
    }
    else if (!mExtras.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT).isEmpty())
    {
        mPostTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.postText);
        mPostText = mExtras.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        mPostTextView.setText(mPostText);
        mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagePreview_container);
        mImageView.setImageURI((Uri) mExtras.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM));
    }
}

private void getHashKey()
{
    // Used for test purposes.
    // Need to set this in facebook https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ under key hashes in the android platform.
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getString(R.string.app_package_name), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

        for (Signature signature : info.signatures)
        {
            try {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");

                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsa)
            {
                Log.d("exception" , "No algorithmn");
                Assert.assertTrue(false);
            }
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException nnfe)
    {
        Log.d("exception" , "Name not found");
        Assert.assertNull("Name not found", nnfe);
    }
}

public void postButtonPressed(View view)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Sharing to Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mPendingAction = true;
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        session = new Session(getApplicationContext());
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Session.OpenRequest openSessionRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(this);
    }
    else
    {
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED))
        {
            // Session is not opened or closed, session is created but not opened.
            session = new Session(this);
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            session.openForPublish(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(callback).setPermissions(PERMISSION));
        }
        else
        {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }
    }
    Session.setActiveSession(session);
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
{
    if(exception != null)
    {
        // Handle exception here.
        Log.v("Facebook CALLBACK", "Facebook login error " + exception);
        return;
    }
    if (state != null && state.isOpened()) {

        if (session.isPermissionGranted(PERMISSION))
        {
            if (mPendingAction)
            {
                // Session ready to make requests.
                postImageToFacebook();
                mPendingAction = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Get the permissions if we don't have them.
            try {
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSION));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Access denied for publish.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
    else if (state.isClosed())
    {
        // Session logged out.
        return;
    }
}


private void postImageToFacebook() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    final Uri uri = (Uri) mExtras.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    final String extraText = mPostTextView.getText().toString();
    if (session.isPermissionGranted("publish_actions"))
    {
        Bundle param = new Bundle();

        // Add the image
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArrayData = stream.toByteArray();
            param.putByteArray("picture", byteArrayData);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // The image that was send through is now not there?
            Assert.assertTrue(false);
        }

        // Add the caption
        param.putString("message", extraText);
        Request request = new Request(session,"me/photos", param, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                addNotification(getString(R.string.photo_post), response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());

            }
        }, null);
        RequestAsyncTask asyncTask = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        asyncTask.execute();
        clearToken();
        finish();
    }
}
private void clearToken() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isClosed()) {
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }
}
private void addNotification(String message, GraphObject result, FacebookRequestError error)
{
    String title = null;
    String alertMessage = null;
    if (error == null) {
        title = getString(R.string.success);
        String id = result.cast(GraphObjectWithId.class).getId();
        alertMessage = getString(R.string.successfully_posted_post, message, id);
    } else {
        title = getString(R.string.error);
        alertMessage = error.getErrorMessage();
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(alertMessage);
    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
    // started Activity.
    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
    // your application to the Home screen.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    int mId = 0;
    mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
}

private interface GraphObjectWithId extends GraphObject {
    String getId();
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
    {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
}
```

I also checked my facebook app mode, it is already in public mode.
Thank you.

Comment: You need to submit publish_actions for review

Comment: you mean to said i need to set publish_action for review on facebook app account!!! here https://developers.facebook.com

Comment: @WizKid do you mean we have to refer this link?  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login